# Need to change pivot points during animation

Tags: animation

First of all sorry for my english.

I create an animation of duplicating triangles that are ultimately to create a shape. Triangles are created by rotating around a vertex or edge. The problem arises when the first group of triangles appears (dark gray in the picture) and I would like the shape to grow. To achieve this, it is necessary to change the pivot point.

How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is a series of rotations for your triangle, what you could do is use ***Child Of*** constraints with some empties:

- Create an empty at the first pivot point of the triangle, give your triangle a *Child Of* constraint with the empty as *Target*, press the *Set Inverse* button, keyframe the empty:

[image]

- Rotate the empty, keyframe the rotation, put the 3D cursor on the second pivot point, create an empty, give your triangle a second *Child Of* constraint with this second empty as *Target* and *Set Inverse*, keyframe this empty:

[image]
[image]

- Rotate this second empty, keyframe.

[image]